# Another short riddle. Left alone, I'm a thing that this riddle has not

Tags: riddle, word

Left alone, I'm a thing that this riddle has not

<strike>By every good writer I shan't be forgot</strike>  **Author's edit:** This line has been deemed misleading and unfit for publication. The second line of the riddle titled "Another short riddle" shall henceforth be replaced with the following: *It's a thing that is a word that has some letters and definitions.*

<strike>Rearranged, if you shout this, you might be a liar</strike> **Author's edit, 2:** Well, this is embarrassing. Again, replace with the following: *The word described above is an anagram of another word. If shouted, it may have been done so by a liar... or not... You never can tell with that sort of thing.*

<strike>Again, if shouted, it's a pun used a lot.</strike> **Author's edit, 3:** Apologies, again. I hang my head in shame for such sloppy riddling. Replace with: *This word is again an anagram of the two above. It's rather popular as a pun, replacing another word with this.*

Comment: How vocabularious! I had fun reading the debate over the LAIR line, all things I considered before posting (can I call a LAIR cold or poorly lit?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After the last one, I feel obligated to go with my initial gut on this one (though I'm admittedly less confident, might be a bit stretched). My guess is that the word is:

> FLOW

Left alone, I'm a thing that this riddle has not

> The riddle certainly lacks this, what with the author's edits

By every good writer I shan't be forgot/It's a thing that is a word that has some letters and definitions.

> Flow is important in a writing style for the sake of cohesion. As for the revised line, I can't garner anything. While I suspect that this line is the source of some wordplay, maybe it's just as simple as it seems.

Rearranged, if you shout this, you might be a liar/The word described above is an anagram of another word. If shouted, it may have been done so by a liar... or not... You never can tell with that sort of thing.

> WOLF is an anagram of flow, and for any familiar with the story of The Boy Who Cried Wolf, it makes sense that someone shouting it might be questioned.

Again, if shouted it's a pun used a lot/This word is again an anagram of the two above. It's rather popular as a pun, replacing another word with this

> FOWL is, I believe at least, a common pun replacing or being replaced by the word FOUL (e.g. a murder most fowl).

Like last time, I could be barking up the wrong tree. Hopefully not though!

Comment: OH. MY. GOD. I literally saw the line about the pun, thought the word 'fowl' immediately (for whatever reason), and couldn't make WOLF fit. How did I not remember the boy who cried wolf? ;-; +1

Comment: @NeedAName strikes again! You're just 91 up-votes short of your [recent record!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle) ;) For the record, since "shout" takes the place of "cry" in the phrase *cry wolf*, the last line also references the pun *cry fowl*. Gotta trust that gut of yours!