# What am I? I always play fair

Tags: riddle, word

What am I?

> A word of 6 letters,
>   I always play fair
>   
> Minus my first I am cold
>   
> Minus my last and jumbled,
>   
> I'll give you a massage
>   
> Jumble my whole,
>   
> You'll learn nothing from me
>   
> I always play fair

Hint to those still trying to solve it:

> (You probably know [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle) by @roland by now.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer is:

> CHEAT

A word of 6 letters,
I always play fair

> A CHEAT doesn't play fair, and it's not 6 letters.

Minus my first I am cold

> HEAT isn't cold.

Minus my last and jumbled, 
I'll give you a massage

> You might need a massage if you have an ACHE.

Jumble my whole,
You'll learn nothing from me

> TEACHing makes you learn things.

I always play fair

> Every clue is wrong because the narrator is cheating. (aka same gimmick as [this other one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle))

Comment: Nice :) Well done!

Comment: How do you even figure that... at all

Comment: Moral, never assume things.

Comment: This is exactly why i always question hints of other riddles