# A much harder riddle - Nothing at all

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> By myself, a long word
>   Innocent and true
>   If you scramble me
>   Dubious is the clue
>   Again and you will
>   Regret nothing at all
>   Once more and
>   I'm a person who overall
>   
> Has nothing to use
>   
> Nothing at all

This is a much harder riddle, so feeling generous: here's a mysterious hint...

> Not all is as it seems...

Have fun with this one!

Comment: You [already did this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25731/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is it the word

> Ruse?

```
By myself, a long word
Innocent and true
```

> Ruse isn't a long word and its a falsehood not true

```
If you scramble me
Dubious is the clue
```

> If you are SURE you are not dubious

```
Again and you will
Regret nothing at all
```

> RUES means you regret something

```
Once more and
I'm a person who overall 
Has nothing to use 
Nothing at all
```

> Not sure about this one but I think its the last anagram of ruse, USER. If you are a user you are a person who is using something

So

> This whole riddle is a RUSE