# Riddle: Am I a number or not?

Tags: riddle

I am a number above 3,
saying I'm 4 and above and you would disagree;
although I am seen as a very large number,
in a paper fills with squares.

Before I make your head spin,
I will give you a hint;
I cannot find the correct tags for this question,
but everyone abuse me with obsession!

What am I?

Hints:

> 1. Some said I'm round as a pi(e), but in a way I'm closer to a knife.
>   2. One of my favorite game is Tic-Tac-Toe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> An octothorpe, hash-mark, pound-sign, number-sign ... **#**

I am a number above 3,

> You are a "number" sign, above the 3 key on many keyboards

saying I'm 4 and above and you would disagree;

> Right

although I am seen as a very large number,
in a paper fills with squares.

> In an Excel spreadsheet, overlarge numbers that don't fit in their column are displayed as **####**

Before I make your head spin,
I will give you a hint;
I cannot find the correct tags for this question,
but everyone abuse me with obsession!

> #foo is a hashtag, this is a reference to such tags

Comment: +1 for thinking! Also imagin how 2-2 vertical & horizontal cuts from knife will look on a pie!

Comment: And we have a winner!  However i'll accept after you figured out line 3 & 4.  Hints - I call this paper a 'sheet'

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> Pi. (3.14159265359...).

And So, i believe it can be easily arrived at as follows:

> The first two lines say it's a number above 3 but less than 4...Pi suffices that of course.

The next line tells us:

> It's seen as a very large number...but you can realize it only in a paper filled with squares...that #area concept.And we hit on Pi all the more. :)

However, Finally:

> The next and the last clue that speaks of obsession holds, as we have a salient thing called Pi obsession ( apart from the mathematical community as well).

Comment: ninja'd me, well done!

Comment: Thanks @BeastlyGerbil :) You can only be sure when you get upvtes though. ;) =D. Haha.

Comment: Can you explain your answer, please? Answers without explanation are deleted.

Comment: @Deusovi Kindly note that there's almost nothing to explain. The first two lines say it's a number above 3 but less than 4...it's seen as a very large number...but you can realize it only in a paper filled with squares...that #area concept. And the next two lines are of no significance...neither is the penultimate line...but the last one that speaks of obsession holds, as we have a salient thing called Pi obsession ( apart from the mathematical community as well). Hope you'll agree. :)

Comment: I think you're correct about what the answer is - why not put that explanation in your actual answer?

Comment: ^ You still need to explain the lines in the answer, even if they seem arbitrary, not everyone will understand.

Comment: Okay sure... :)

Comment: Done @Deusovi .

Comment: Please see [the layout of the answer here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle) for you should answer riddles. Line by line is the general requirement, or 2x2... etc. It makes it look neater too

Comment: Followed @BeastlyGerbil

Comment: I've to admit this answer fits every line very nicely, except for line 7!  Wish I could give 2 upvotes, but this is not the answer!

Comment: Wonderful answer. Just one tiny thing that I want to point out. Try to avoid using "thanks" and its synonyms at the end of the answer. It's not wrong or anything. It just makes it sound cheesy and people here, tend to respect a straight answer rather than one that is slightly odd. something that makes the answerer/puzzler sound extra-polite is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat out-there guess:

you are

> 9

I am a number above 3, saying I'm 4 and above and you would disagree;

> On the computer number-pad, 9 is above 3, but not 4

although I am seen as a very large number, in a paper fills with squares.

> 9 is the largest possible number in a game of Sudoku

Before I make your head spin [...] everyone abuse me with obsession!

> A stretch, but if you spin the aforementioned number-pad, you are left with the layout of a phone keypad, which are often abused with obsession.

Comment: Good guess!  You were very close with the first line, however someone have gotten the answer already.