# Another strange Riley riddle

Tags: riddle, word

Here is a new Riley riddle.

> My prefix is how [@Duck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51172/duck) eats(no offense),
>
> My suffix is the most popular here,
>
> My infix is a someone who does something wrong in Romania,
>
> Altogether is what I am.

Comment: *"My prefix is how @Duck eats (no offence),"* xD I am favouriting this $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you

> PECULIAR? (Sorry, I had to!)

My prefix is how @Duck eats(no offense),

> Eats by PEC(king) at food.

My suffix is the most popular here,

> As found by @PerpetualJ, this is LIAR.

My infix is a someone who does something wrong in Romania,

> In Romanian, ECUL translates to "FAILURE".

Altogether is what I am.

> A very peculiar riddle, this. @Yout Ried insists that they are in fact the peculiar one!

Comment: Ohh that fits with the title too! +1

Comment: This was my solution as well. Nice work!

Comment: Lol I meant by the answer is that I was your answer

Answer (score 5):

### **Partial Answer**

---

Currently working this in chunks.

*My prefix is how [@Duck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51172/duck) eats (no offense).*

> Ducks are broken down into two categories, dabblers and divers. Dabblers eat in shallow water, while divers, well, you get the point. The prefix could be **dab**, **dive**, or in the case of [@Duck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51172/duck), since his photo is of a rubber duck, they typically *eat* water in the bathtub and thus the prefix could also be **suck** since they *suck* in the water through a hole.
>  This could also quite literally be **eat** since technically [@Duck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51172/duck) *eats* by *eating*.

*My suffix is the most popular here.*

> - [A Short Brutal Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle) by [@Roland](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13237/roland) which is the most popular riddle here. The answer is **liar**.

*My infix kills millions; My infix is a someone who does something wrong in Romania.*

> Previously I had **war** and **time** in which **war** was correct, but the puzzle has changed and this is now wrong.
>  I'm not sure but a criminal in Romanian is a *penal*. Combining this with the suffix yields no results.

*Altogether is what I am.*

> 

### **Interesting Finds**

---

Hahaha okay, I couldn't resist adding this in. I always post things I find interesting on my search with my answers.

> [Meatware](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/8282/meatware): Meatware refers to the human element within a computer system. Along with hardware and software, meatware, or a human, is required to operate a computer system. Meatware is also known as wetware or liveware.

Comment: nevemind I screwed up between 2 riddles I had in mind

Comment: you're suffix correct

Comment: What exactly is correct in my post here? Put it in a rot13.com comment so I can clean this up.

Comment: yeah im sooo sorry

Comment: See my edited comment please

Comment: lbhe fhssvk. (yvne)

Comment: Good find on the suffix, @PerpetualJ!! :D

Comment: @YoutRied Can I get a clear hint on the infix or prefix? I'm lost here and keep running into dead ends.

Comment: A rot13(guvrs va Ebznavna vf "ubg").  not that this helps me, but perhaps it will help you

Answer (score 3):

Partial: infix

> OD - millions of people die of overdosing.
> POX - a plague that had millions of victims. Does not fit as much as OD imo, because 'kills' is in present tense but pox is more a problem of the past

Comment: Oh my oops my suffix was the wrong thing... oops I gotta fix that please check the updated version in a bit – Yout Ried 1 min ago   edit

Comment: sorry, but you're not on the right track

Answer (score 3):

A wild stab in the dark.

Are you:

> Tableware?

My prefix is how @Duck eats

> I don't know @Duck personally but maybe he eats off a *TABLE*?

My suffix sounds like an undefined place,

> *WARE* sounds like "where" - an undefined place

My infix kills millions

> Millions die in shootings where they get "blown away" - *BLEW*.

Comment: Oh my oops my suffix was the wrong thing... oops I gotta fix that please check the updated version in a bit