# The answer is the same (tricky puzzle!)

Tags: word, crosswords, acrostic

Fill in the right words and the answer can be read across. Enjoy!

> 1. Expensive
> 2. Automatic
> 3. Life
> 4. Shrink
> 5. Nadir
> 6. Named
> 7. Winter

[image]

Comment: I think it's a *good* puzzle and upvoted it. Don't think it was very tricky though ;c)

Comment: Everyone is just too good! I guess I have to come up with a proper difficult one ;)

Comment: Jup, the *combined* brain-power of users here is *way* up my league. Well, the brain-power of some individuals already is, I guess ;c) Which, of course, makes me proud I've still a few "unanswered" questions in my portfolio. Hopefully unanswered because difficult and not because bad.

Comment: Isn't this just a different presentation of the same concept as https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/20233/34791?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A *tricky* one indeed! The answers to the puzzle are:

> Words which mean the *opposite* to the clue!

Like so:

> 1. Expensive = CHE**A**P
>  2. Automatic = MA**N**UAL
>  3. Life = DEA**T**H
>  4. Shrink = GR**O**W
>  5. Nadir = ZE**N**ITH
>  6. Named = ANON**Y**MOUS
>  7. Winter = SUM**M**ER

The shaded letters going down spell:

> **ANTONYM** - which literally means 'a word with the opposite meaning'!

Comment: Great answer, and obviously correct! This answer is most complete, even though it was posted a whole minute after @trolley813 's answer ;) So I accepted this one

Comment: Why did you pick just those letters? Is there a pattern?

Comment: @Duck They're the letters corresponding to the shaded cells in the diagram. Reading *down* them (as the antonym to 'across' specified in the puzzle instructions) yields the solution...

Comment: Oh, didn't see the diagram.

Comment: Just curious, what lead you to your answer? I can see maybe a lot of trial and error, but didn’t really pick up on this lol

Comment: @PerpetualJ It just sorta clicked immediately. My first thought was that it couldn't just be a straightforward acrostic crossword, because that would be far too simple for PSE. The use of 'same' in the title immediately connected with 'opposite' in my mind, so I tried it for the first 2 (both were found quickly) and the rest followed from there!

Answer (score 18):

The answer is

> Antonym (roughly an opposite of "the same")

Because

> the words are opposites (antonyms) of the clues:
>  1. CheAp 2. MaNual 3. DeaTh 4. GrOw 5. ZeNith 6. AnonYmous 7. SumMer

Comment: Snap! Well played... +1

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted your answer, I think your one is much more beautifully styled than mine.