# A slightly normal puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I found a very odd puzzle some time ago. I thought it was interesting, when I realized it was my own puzzle! Somehow I had no memory of creating it. Well, it turns out that I also created another puzzle, and something tells me they are related. Here it is:

```
Raseac my queen 21 is not what you need. 

euf pgzwqd, euf pgzwqd, euf imkxmke pgzwqd


Nothing normal is found at the end 

448
667
221
444
912

Add in the letters, starting from top to bottom, not changing each non-word

Dicio hondtd ghafcnfge btbhniags dhdtadt nieda'bnet ibiec dhanedgchd. 
Mfnafgy tnhbisbga darded jistuab isiac hdeyhtd afpgpafer. 
Tnbsbhiag idkdled ltsrbaetei oicri mnduesdhbr farfeg bujsbta soegmidthdnd, togiahnnibi oicrmie, dhdofr mfafepgxle 'byba' dndadd 'ikba' riaiec djsduht 'fyfg' abadnb 'ddkd' nabtoi 'ichwcy' dadndh 'Ofkgf.'
Tyebhba daedrd iaubjst iticnmeohisg.


more than a 1/2 or less than 1/4
```

---

Everything above the line is part of the puzzle.

Here's a hint to help you along:

> along with the puzzle, a smudged note was found saying something about a lair.

I'll accept an answer that doesn't have it, but if you want a fully complete answer see if you can explain this hint.

Hint #2

> This puzzle is partially inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle)

Comment: Is "dicio" a cipher-encoded or is it deeper than that?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath It is rot13(Qrsvavgryl n yvggyr qrrcre)

Answer (score 3):

**Another partial**

If the column of numbers is interpreted as

> letters (where A=1, etc), we get the letter groups **ddh, ffg, bba, ddd, iab.** If we then go through the scrambled text, we see that each word contains the letters from one of these groups (actually there seems to be an additional group of **ici**). If we remove the group letters from each word and rearrange the remaining letters

we get:

> *Do not change things that needn’t be changed.*
>  *Many things are just as they appear.*
>  *Things like letters or numbers are just something, nothing more, for example ‘y’ and ‘k’ are just ‘y’ and ‘k’ not ‘why’ and ‘Ok’.*
>  *They are just something.*

Comment: Also rot13(Gur "vpv" pbzrf sebz n qvssrerag dhrfgvba bs zvar gung unf n gvgyr pbzcyrgryl bccbfvgr guvf bar.)

Answer (score 2):

## Partial

This answer is only to help others along on their puzzle-solving journey.

The second line ("euf...") is encrytped with a

> Caesar Cipher with a shift of 12

and says

> sit dunker, sit dunker, sit waylays dunker

Comment: rot13(gur fuvsg jnf gjryir, abg sbhegrra)

Comment: rot13(Vg vf gjryir gb rapbqr naq sbhegrra gb qrpbqr, bayl guvegrra vf flzzrgevpny).

Comment: rot13(Bu, V frr jung lbh ner fnlvat)

Comment: @MilesZew - Fixed! And you don't need to put everything in rot13. It's a bit of a pain TBH. :)

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath That's true, I just get into the habit of doing it :)