# Not a good policy

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is quite a stunner,
>   my preinfix sharpens edges,
>   my postinfix accepts cuckoos,
>   my suffix is full of porkies.
>   I am a collection of lies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are

> DISHONESTY.

*My prefix is quite a stunner,*

> DISH, in its colloquial sense as an attractive person.

*my preinfix sharpens edges,*

> HONE, as in to hone a blade.

*my postinfix accepts cuckoos,*

> NEST, where a cuckoo lays its eggs.

*my suffix is full of porkies.*

> STY. Not the porkies you were thinking of!

*I am a collection of lies.*

> DISHONESTY, not a good policy.

The "in" for me on this riddle was the second line, since there's a specific term for something that sharpens edges. Then I noticed that that term is contained in a word that relates to lies, and the rest is history. (I did waste a bit of time before that by trying to interpret every line as a falsehood, wondering if there'd be a common theme like [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/20233/5373).)

Comment: I'm glad you related it to that puzzle and that the title wasn't a giveaway. Your in is the only thing slightly different, I thought of the plural. All, this isn't a cynical q, just play. If taken time, may have found a food related theme. Further, I really appreciate you giving feedback.

Comment: Never knew dish had that alternative meaning. The more you know... Great puzzle @Tom