# To be honest, we're genuine

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> To be honest, we're genuine; Hoaxes we don't like
> Elephants are similar;unlike a riding bike
> A truthteller we are; Never tell a lie
> Swap letters and then you find: Words that mean fly.

> Explode a letter: Rearrange, I am not an ape
> Surprisingly the truth is; far from what it seems
> For everyone says we're not a person with a cape.

> And now you know the truth: Kindness is not our trait
> Everyone despises me, the jail might be my fate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> *fake*.

> At least, that's what the capitalized letters tell me.

Comment: (rot13) Gur nafjre vf snxr, ohg ubj qbrf vg svg jvgu gur bgure yvarf bs gur evqqyr? Uvag: Gur obggbz 2 yvarf ner qvssrerag sebz gur gbc 5 fbzrubj.

Comment: @Stevo Does it have to? I found the answer. It's hidden in the text. That's a valid way of solving a puzzle, no?

Comment: It is, but the lines itself has some meaing towards the answer.

Comment: @Stevo I look forward to reading what it is.

Answer (score 1):

## Wrap up and Answer for *To be honest we're genuine*

*This is a solution to the puzzle and provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been [approved by the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

CAUTION: This post contains spoilers for the puzzle.

---

Being familiar with

> [This puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle), I decided to make a riddle somewhat like that.

I started by

> Trying to find an answer that might indicate that the lines are incorrect, and I came up with Fake.

Thinking it was going to be too hard...

> I made sure that the capitals gave a hint: *The answer is fake*

That gave us another way of thinking with it:

> The line gives us the answer, but if someone didn't know that I was pointing towards the answer, it might serve as a hint that the lines are incorrect, or fake.

With that, I started making the riddle,

> Making sure that the first 3 lines were fake, or incorrect. And then the middle 3 lines have some truth, and the last 2 lines were true. Thats a what *fake* (as in person) would have done. They got caught... and they end up spilling the truth. Hence the truth in the last few lines. Another subtle hint towards the word fake.

### For the intended solution path...

> To be honest, we are genuine, hoaxes we dont' like

> So, everything here was fake. 'To be honest', they arent' really honest, and fakes is definitely not genuine. A fake thing might be a hoax; a fake thing does like hoaxes, after all thats what they are!

> Elephants are similar;unlike a riding bike

> An elephant and fake has no relation whatsoever, so its fake, same for the 2nd part. A riding *bike* has similarities as in it ends in the same 2 letters.

> A truthteller we are; Never tell a lie

> Hopefully no-one needs an explanation for this

> Swap letters and then you find: Words that mean fly.

> Swap them for yourself; no word can even be made!

> Explode a letter: Rearrange, I am not an ape
>
> Surprisingly the truth is; far from what it seems
>
> For everyone says we're not a person with a cape.

> All 3 lines here has some truth in it here, with some fake parts

> And now you know the truth: Kindness is not our trait
>
> Everyone despises me, the jail might be my fate.

> Now this is the full truth, the jail might be where a fake goes, kindness is usually not a fake's trait.